# Extract a running ELF from a memory dump

Tags: elf, dump, computer-forensics

Our teacher gave us as homework a memory dump from a VBox (Ubuntu 16.04.9) and said that the message we need to get is printed by an ELF currently running in the VM.
This is my what I get after running `pslist` on the image.

```
Offset             Name                 Pid             PPid            Uid             Gid    DTB                Start Time
------------------ -------------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ------ ------------------ ----------
0xffff88007c998000 systemd              1               0               0               0      0x000000003552e000 -
0xffff88007c998e00 kthreadd             2               0               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c999c00 ksoftirqd/0          3               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99aa00 kworker/0:0          4               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99b800 kworker/0:0H         5               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99c600 kworker/u4:0         6               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99d400 rcu_sched            7               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99e200 rcu_bh               8               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99f000 migration/0          9               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f0000 watchdog/0           10              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f1c00 watchdog/1           11              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f2a00 migration/1          12              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f3800 ksoftirqd/1          13              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f4600 kworker/1:0          14              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f5400 kworker/1:0H         15              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f6200 kdevtmpfs            16              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f7000 netns                17              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca90000 perf                 18              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca90e00 khungtaskd           19              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca91c00 writeback            20              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca92a00 ksmd                 21              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca93800 khugepaged           22              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca94600 crypto               23              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca95400 kintegrityd          24              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca96200 bioset               25              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca97000 kblockd              26              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb80000 ata_sff              27              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb80e00 md                   28              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb81c00 devfreq_wq           29              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb82a00 kworker/u4:1         30              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb83800 kworker/0:1          31              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb84600 kworker/1:1          32              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb86200 kswapd0              34              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb87000 vmstat               35              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec0000 fsnotify_mark        36              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec0e00 ecryptfs-kthrea      37              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f27000 kthrotld             53              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb85400 acpi_thermal_pm      54              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fc8000 bioset               55              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fc8e00 bioset               56              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fc9c00 bioset               57              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcaa00 bioset               58              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcb800 bioset               59              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcc600 bioset               60              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcd400 bioset               61              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fce200 bioset               62              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcf000 scsi_eh_0            63              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f26200 scsi_tmf_0           64              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f24600 scsi_eh_1            65              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f22a00 scsi_tmf_1           66              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f20e00 kworker/u4:2         67              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f25400 kworker/u4:3         68              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec6200 ipv6_addrconf        72              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035595400 deferwq              85              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035596200 charger_manager      86              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035593800 bioset               87              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034c49c00 kworker/0:2          126             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff8800355e5400 kpsmoused            139             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034ee8e00 kworker/0:3          156             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec2a00 kworker/1:1H         166             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034eef000 scsi_eh_2            167             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034eee200 scsi_tmf_2           168             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034eed400 bioset               169             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f23800 raid5wq              241             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035590000 bioset               272             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035594600 kworker/0:1H         295             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035597000 jbd2/sda1-8          297             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035590e00 ext4-rsv-conver      298             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034c4aa00 systemd-journal      354             1               0               0      0x0000000079614000 -
0xffff880035592a00 iscsi_eh             356             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880079103800 kworker/1:2          370             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034eeaa00 kauditd              372             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a478e00 ib_addr              382             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a479c00 ib_mcast             385             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a47aa00 ib_nl_sa_wq          386             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a47b800 ib_cm                387             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a47c600 iw_cm_wq             389             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a47d400 rdma_cm              391             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec4600 lvmetad              394             1               0               0      0x000000007c36c000 -
0xffff88007a478000 kworker/1:3          399             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880079100000 systemd-udevd        408             1               0               0      0x000000007c2c8000 -
0xffff880079100e00 iprt-VBoxWQueue      493             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034ebf000 ttm_swap             649             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a076200 atd                  730             1               0               0      0x000000007c3f8000 -
0xffff88007a070000 lxcfs                738             1               0               0      0x0000000079fe0000 -
0xffff88007b68b800 accounts-daemon      739             1               0               0      0x0000000079fe2000 -
0xffff880034eb8e00 rsyslogd             745             1               104             108    0x0000000079530000 -
0xffff880034c4e200 cron                 754             1               0               0      0x000000007a08c000 -
0xffff88007942c600 systemd-logind       758             1               0               0      0x000000007a6d6000 -
0xffff880079429c00 acpid                777             1               0               0      0x000000007917c000 -
0xffff880079428000 snapd                783             1               0               0      0x0000000079768000 -
0xffff880079428e00 dbus-daemon          785             1               107             111    0x0000000079470000 -
0xffff88007b17b800 dhclient             846             1               0               0      0x000000007a430000 -
0xffff88007942aa00 polkitd              898             1               0               0      0x0000000079b92000 -
0xffff880034ebd400 mdadm                907             1               0               0      0x000000007c3fc000 -
0xffff88007b17f000 VBoxService          941             1               0               0      0x000000007862e000 -
0xffff880034ebc600 named                1018            1               110             115    0x0000000079aa4000 -
0xffff88007a32c600 sshd                 1023            1               0               0      0x0000000034dbc000 -
0xffff88007b179c00 iscsid               1036            1               0               0      0x000000007afdc000 -
0xffff88007b178e00 iscsid               1037            1               0               0      0x0000000079bd0000 -
0xffff88007b68f000 irqbalance           1079            1               0               0      0x000000007a462000 -
0xffff88007b688000 login                1084            1               0               1000   0x0000000079dc0000 -
0xffff88007a074600 systemd              1157            1               1000            1000   0x0000000034c16000 -
0xffff88007a073800 (sd-pam)             1160            1157            1000            1000   0x0000000079a92000 -
0xffff88007a075400 bash                 1166            1084            1000            1000   0x0000000035720000 -
0xffff8800355e3800 ht0p                 1192            1166            1000            1000   0x000000007b982000 -
0xffff8800355e6200 htop                 1193            1166            1000            1000   0x000000007b9a2000 -
```

I have tried running `procdump` on a lot of processes there and then running `strings` on them but nothing seemed like the 'message'. I really have no idea what to do next, do I need to extract somehow the ELF that's running from memory? Also do you have any idea what process it might be or what else should I do?

Comment: Maybe one of these processes looks like it's impersonating another (speculating)? Also, there is a Volatility plugin called `linux_bash` that may shed some light by extracting bash history from memory. Hard to say more without having my hands on the image but sounds fun

Comment: what is `ht0p`? Look at the tail end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure it is an ELF file, and if the file has a .ELF extension, then you could use the Volatility dumpfiles module and search for a regex that matches .ELF like so...

```
vol.py --profile=$PROFILE -f $MEMPATH dumpfiles -n -i -r \\.elf --dump-dir=$OUTDIR
```

-n : Use original file name in output
-r : Use regex
-i : Case insensitive

Comment: Sorry I was so late to answer, lol didn't even realize how old this post was.

Comment: No worries Matthew. Someone might come across this answer through a google search and find just what they needed. Thanks for taking the time to contribute!